# What does an identifier followed by a colon mean in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

```
bail:
    if ( err && image ) {
        CGImageRelease( image );
        image = NULL;
    }
    if ( provider ) CGDataProviderRelease( provider );
    if ( colorspace ) CGColorSpaceRelease( colorspace );
    *imageOut = image;
    return err;
```

I looked at some code and found this.  I have never seen this before.  What does `bail:` mean?

It comes from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: You would have made Prof Dijkstra a very happy man. See his classic paper, <https://files.ifi.uzh.ch/rerg/arvo/courses/kvse/uebungen/Dijkstra_Goto.pdf>, from 1968.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bail:` is a label. This is standard C syntax. It's not used very often in properly written code. It's most common use is with `goto`. Please avoid using `goto`. In the code you referenced it is used by the `require` function. If the `require` fails, the code will jump ahead to the `bail` label, skipping all of the other code in between.

Comment: goto is not bad. Language flame wars and all. Over use of it is bad. But it is no worse than anything else that compiles to a jmp in assembly unless it is over-used and poorly documented.

Comment: Few realize that if they look at their compiled code, it is actually filled with gotos in the object file.  A jmp instruction is nothing but a goto with a different name

Comment: @RandyHoward Just because the assembly has lots of jumps doesn't mean that the human readable, human maintained, higher level code should be filled with calls to `goto`. Spaghetti code is trouble waiting to happen.

Comment: Nobody said to fill it with gotos.  Mindlessly avoiding it completely, even when the resulting code without the goto is more spaghetti like than the one with is not a good idea either.  All things in their appropriate place.

Comment: The concrete argument against goto is the same as against exceptions;  both add execution paths that may be completely different from the normal, linear, if this-or-that execution path.   This introduces complexity and incurs fragility.

Answer (score 7):

It's a label that the `goto` statement jumps to.

The code you're looking at, `SquareCamViewController.m`, uses a macro named `require`, like this:

```
require( error == nil, bail );
```

This macro is defined in the `AssertMacros.h` header file.  It takes a label as its second argument, and uses `goto` if the first argument evaluates to false.

Using `goto` to jump to cleanup code at the end of a function is the most common use of `goto` and labels in C.

Comment: @RandyHoward really>>>why?i just thought this answer is more detail so i pick the first answer...